# Not able to access directive using @ContentChild

Tags: angular, directive, angular2-directives

I have a directive as follow:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[expTemplate]',
})
export class ExpTemplateDirective {
    constructor() { }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    exports: [ExpTemplateDirective],
    declarations: [ExpTemplateDirective]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

which I am passing to my **dropdown** component from **header**  as follow

```
    <dropdown [items]="navItem.subMenu" dropDownType="navMenu xs-hide sm-hide" [theme]="'dropdown-primary'" [placement]="'left'">
        <a *ngIf="navItem.type !== 'ng2'" href="{{navItem.link}}">{{navItem.text}}</a>
        <a *ngIf="navItem.type === 'ng2'" href="{{navItem.link}}">{{navItem.text}}</a>
        <template expTemplate let-item>
            <a  href="{{item.link}}">{{item.text}}</a>
         </template>
    </dropdown>
```

Now I am tring to access that expTemplate directive on my **dropdown** component but I am getting it undefined

```
@ContentChild(ExpTemplateDirective) templateRef: ExpTemplateDirective;
```

I am not able to understand what I missing here please help me....

Comment: Use `@ViewChild()`. ContentChild is for when your template has projected content in it (`<ng-content>`).

Comment: it will be in my ng-content

Comment: I have pass it in html for the dropdown component

Comment: Maybe you're trying to access the property **too soon**? It's only set after the  `ngAfterContentInit()` hook.

Comment: I am trying it ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Please provide ALL the information when you first ask the question, it will be easier to help you... At this point, hard to tell what's wrong without a Plunkr.

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer for this?